# How do I bring my user input to another method?

Tags: c#

```cs
public void PlayerChooseDraw()
{
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    Console.WriteLine("Number of cards in the deck is: " + deck.CardCount);
    Console.WriteLine("-------------");
    Console.WriteLine("How many cards do you want to draw? You can draw between 1 to 26");

    int playerDraw = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (playerDraw > 26) {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Maximum cards to draw is 26 !");
        PlayerChooseDraw();
    }
    else if (playerDraw < 1) {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Minimum cards to draw is 1 !");
        PlayerChooseDraw();
    }
    else {
        Console.Clear();
        DeckCreation(playerDraw);         
    }
}

public void DeckCreation(?) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(playerDraw);
}
```

How can I bring the integer variable `playerDraw` to `DeckCreation` method without changing it to string or something other? Thank you.

Comment: So if `playerDraw` was a string, you would know how to pass it to `DeckCreation()`? How would you do that?

Comment: Make method definition include an integer : public void DeckCreation(int playerDraw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can direcly pass the integer to be printed by the method like this:

```
public void PrintNumberOfCards(int count)
{ 
  Console.WriteLine(count.ToString());
}
```

I renamed `playerDraw` to `countCardsToDraw` to be more clean and relevant, thus we can call the method like that:

```
int countCardsToDraw = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

...

PrintNumberOfCards(countCardsToDraw);
```

Also we can use [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) to manage errors:

```
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var countCardsToDraw);
```

Here the value will be `0` in case of non integer entered.

We can check the result to loop on the user input and validate the value:

```
bool isUserInputValid;
do
{
  Console.WriteLine("How many cards do you want to draw? You can draw between 1 to 26:");
  isUserInputValid = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var countCardsToDraw)
                  && countCardsToDraw >= 1
                  && countCardsToDraw <= 26;
  if ( !isUserInputValid )
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong value, retry.");
}
while ( !isUserInputValid );
```